# How to prevent rendering of a given widget when some other widget is on top of it in flutter?

Tags: list, flutter, header, widget, rendering

I would like to have list headers as sticky headers. The background of the given header should be transparent and while scrolling the list element 'under' the header should disappear and the user should see the background image behind the list view.

I am using sticky_headers package to get the sticky header effect. But I am only starting my adventure with flutter and don't know much of the widget rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to accomplish this using ShaderMask. The idea is that i calculate where is the header in my list item and mask this part out.

The crucial part of the list widget is this:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => ListView.builder(
      padding: _padding, itemCount: _sectionCount, itemBuilder: _sectionHeader);

  StickyHeader _sectionHeader(BuildContext context, int sectionIndex) {
    final GlobalKey eventListHeaderKey = GlobalKey();
    final GlobalKey shaderMaskKey = GlobalKey();
    final AppStyle appStyle = AppStyle.of(context);

    return StickyHeader(
        header: Container(
            key: eventListHeaderKey,
            child: _sectionHeaderBuilder(context, sectionIndex)),
        content: ShaderMask(
            key: shaderMaskKey,
            shaderCallback: (Rect rect) =>
                _listShader(appStyle, eventListHeaderKey, shaderMaskKey, rect),
            blendMode: BlendMode.dstIn,
            child: Container(
                child: ListView.builder(
                    physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: _sectionElementsCountHandler(sectionIndex),
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                        _elementBuilder(context, sectionIndex, index)))));
  }

  Shader _listShader(AppStyle appStyle, GlobalKey listHeaderKey,
      GlobalKey shaderMaskKey, Rect rect) {
    final RenderBox listHeaderRenderBox =
        listHeaderKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    final Offset offset = listHeaderRenderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);

    final RenderBox shaderMaskRenderBox =
        shaderMaskKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    final Offset offset2 = shaderMaskRenderBox.globalToLocal(offset);

    return LinearGradient(
        begin: Alignment.topCenter,
        end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        stops: <double>[
          0,
          (rect.top + offset2.dy) / rect.height,
          (rect.top + offset2.dy) / rect.height,
          1
        ],
        colors: <Color>[
          appStyle.colors.transparent,
          appStyle.colors.transparent,
          appStyle.colors.white,
          appStyle.colors.white
        ]).createShader(Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, rect.width, rect.height));
  }
```